# Unknown process attempted to execute code

Tags: antivirus, antimalware, quarantine

This morning I booted up my computer and not long afterward, got a notification from ByteFence (unsubscribed) that an unknown process attempted to execute a command that was deemed unwanted. ByteFence gives me the option to ignore the "threat" and let it execute, but to Block it, I need to pay for their service.

I don't recognize the filename, and a quick Google search didn't turn up any results that were helpful... mostly just weird looking results that look like garbage text. Here is the message from ByteFence:

[image: ryiddps]

As you can see, the executable name is "ryiddps.exe". And the parameter after does seem unusual. I killed the process in Task Manager and deleted the executable, as well as its parent directory, and it hasn't yet re-appeared (in case it's self-replicating), but I don't know whether the damage could already be done, assuming this executable was, in fact, malicious.

Anyone have any ideas what this application was trying to do, or possibly recognize the application name? I'd like to dismiss the damn ByteFence notification, as it's stealing focus from all other applications, but I don't know if I should click Ignore.

Comment: If you still have a copy of ryiddps.exe (recycle bin), I would upload it to VirusTotal, see what that thinks it was.

Comment: @HelpingHand Unfortunately, I was not aware of the existence of that website. I used Shift + Delete, so it's gone.